# Inner Join Laravel - Erro where clause is ambiguous (23000)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou aprendendo a utilizar o FramWork Laravel e me deparei com o seguinte erro as realizar um inner Join (lembrando que já tenho um banco de dados com informações por isso não estou utilizado migrations)

```
$colaborador = DB::table('colaboradores')
    ->join('beneficios','beneficios.colaborador_id','=','colaboradores.colaboradores_id')        
    ->where('colaborador_id',$request->colaborador_id)
    ->get();
```

E gera o erro:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'colaborador_id' in where clause is ambiguous (23000)

mas se eu acessar o banco de dados e fazer o comando:

```
select * from `colaboradores` inner join `beneficios` ON beneficios.colaborador_id = colaboradores.colaborador_id
```

Funciona perfeitamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu **Select** funciona pois está sem cláusula **where**. Se você colocar um `where colaborador_id = 1` na query que executa no banco, você vai ter o mesmo erro.

Isso acontece pois ambas as tabelas possuem `colaborador_id` então no seu **where** você rpecisa especificar qual `colaborador_id` você quer utilizar, o da `colaboradores` ou da `beneficios`.

Para fazer isso basta inserir o `nomedatabela.campo` no seu **where**

```
$colaborador = DB::table('colaboradores')
    ->join('beneficios','beneficios.colaborador_id','=','colaboradores.colaboradores_id')        
    ->where('beneficios.colaborador_id',$request->colaborador_id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Muito obrigado consegui arrumar aqui